# Import/Export running GUI applications between localhost and SSH client running x11 forwarding?

Tags: ssh, x11, xforwarding

I am running a Centos Linux server which I connect to using Putty/SSH with x11 forwarding enabled and an X11 server (Xming) running on the client machine...

I am able to open GUI applications from my Putty session on the client machine but when I end the x11 session the application close and any data is lost...

I have previously seen applications 'grabbed' or exported from a local UNIX server to an ssh client running X11 forwarding and once the user was done - they exported the GUI application back to the server where it continued to run...

This allowed a form of application sharing albeit with just one user running the app at a time but it was very useful...

This was on Solaris and it was a while back... is this possible on Centos Linux and if so, can you give any examples of how this works?